# Assistance with a simple code for Python

Tags: python

Basically, I'm working on a Python fill in the letters type of game (kind of like Hangman).

The problem is I can't seem to get the program to record duplicate points. 
What I mean is:

The program asks the user for a word. That word, let's say....football, is converted into a masked string (ex. ********)

Then it continually asks the user for letter inputs. Let's say the user enters:
f
o
t
b
a
l

And then it fills out the word. For each letter that is guessed correctly, the user is awarded ONE point. But the problem is that for a word like football,only 6 points are awarded because some of the letters are duplicates.

Basically, the way I've coded it, each time a correct letter is guessed, another point is added on top of the overall total points. Is there a better way of doing this that can include the duplicate letters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perhaps use `count()` on the word to see how many times the letter is in the word:

```
word = 'football'
# Code here to take input
# if input is in word:
    points = word.count(the_input)
    award_player(points)
```

Comment: Alright, I figured it out with the count command. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a `list comprehension` combined with `sum()`:

```
>>> s = "foot**ll"
>>> sum([1 for x in s if x != '*'])
6
```